# Python Text Adventure Loop

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am making a very simple text-adventure game in python 3.3.4, and would like to know if there would be any possible way to make it when input does not match a/b it returns to the print command where the question is asked.

Here is what I have currently:

```
import time
import sys
from random import randrange

text = "** Execute Long Intro **"

for c in text:
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    seconds = "0." + str(randrange(1, 2, 1))
    seconds = float(seconds)
    time.sleep(seconds)


time.sleep(1)


obj1 =input('\nDo you \na.) Rest on the ground \nb.) Find a way out of the jungle\n')
if obj1 in ('a'):
    print('You find a comfortable spot on the ground and drift into sleep...')
    time.sleep(.6)
    print('Zzz.\nZzz..\nZzz...')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('You wake to a strange noise, and work your way out of the jungle.') 
    time.sleep(1)

    print('You emerge out of the jungle and walk along the shoreline of a sunny beach')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('** Objective One Completed **')
    time.sleep(2)



elif obj1 == 'b':
    print('You manage to find a path out of the jungle and discover a beach,')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('** Objective One Completed **')
    time.sleep(2)

elif obj1 != ('a','b'):
    print('Uh.')
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `while` loop:

```
obj1 = input(...)

while obj1 not in ('a', 'b'):
    obj1 = input("Invalid. Enter again: ")

if obj1 == 'a':
    ...
elif obj1 == 'b':
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [blessings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings) library.
install it with:

```
pip install blessings
```

and the usage is simple:

```
from blessings import Terminal
term = Terminal()
print term.clear_bol
print '\t{t.yellow}action{t.normal}|{t.green}Done!{t.normal}'.format(t=term)
```

Comment: I installed blessings with pip, and get an invalid syntax error when I runt the code you have provided.

Comment: You got the idea. Fix the error simply.Read the docs on blessing page. I dont see any syntax error in code!

Comment: This answer does not address the question.

Comment: I actually don't know why the hell I wrote this answer 4 years ago.